When did Negiah become part of Halakha
שלום
I am trying to find out around what time Negiah was implemented into Halakha.
In no way I am not trying to disrespect Halakha, I am only trying to understand it in a deeper way.

What do you mean by "Negiah"?

New dupe template?

I suggest that you read the answers to the question referred to in shmosel's comment and edit your question to improve it.

Welcome to MiYodeya Renzo and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

See the answer over there. "Negia" can mean a few different things. Let's just talk about the age of the sources. The Sifra that reads Leviticus as including other intimate touching was written down around 1800 years ago. (If a rabbinic prohibition, then presumably it was developed sometime in the 500 years or so before that.) The first sources explicitly prohibiting handshakes or other non-intimate contact tend to be medieval, but that's their reading of older sources.
